# Xamarin - Hide Cancel button or change it for Ok on Custom Picker

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, .net-5, picker

I have a Xamarin Forms project on visual studio 2019.

I wanted to hide the cancel button from a simple Picker but wasn't able to do so, so I have now a custom picker but don't know how to remove that button. Either that or changing the "Cancel" button for an "Ok" would be what I want.

The thing is the examples that I have seen are customizing this by using the `NumberPicker` class and this won't work for me as I don't want to display my list that way.

My `CustomPicker` class

```
public class CustomPicker : Picker
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty =
             BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(string), typeof(CustomPicker), string.Empty);

        public string Image
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

My `CustomPickerRenderer` class on `Android` project

```
  public class CustomPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer
    {
        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        CustomPicker element;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            element = (CustomPicker)this.Element;

            if (Control != null && this.Element != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {
                Control.Background = AddPickerStyles(element.Image);
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            }

        }
        public LayerDrawable AddPickerStyles(string imagePath)
        {
            ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
            border.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
            border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            border.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

            Drawable[] layers = { border, GetDrawable(imagePath) };
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            return layerDrawable;
        }
        private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imagePath)
        {
            int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imagePath, "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
            var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, resID);
            var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

            var result = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true));
            result.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Right;

            return result;
        }

    }
```

My `CustomPickerRenderer` on `iOS` project

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var element = (CustomPicker)this.Element;

            if (this.Control != null && this.Element != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {
                var downarrow = UIImage.FromBundle(element.Image);
                Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                Control.RightView = new UIImageView(downarrow);
                Control.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this? Please help and thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093326/199364

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have already seen that and isn't working for me. I don't know how to achieve what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can set a **donetextproperty** in your picker and set it in the uibuttontext on ios side.like:

```
 public class MyPicker:Picker
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty DonebuttonTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DonebuttonText", typeof(string),
            typeof(string), null);
        

            public string DonebuttonText { get { return (string)GetValue(DonebuttonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DonebuttonTextProperty, value); }
        }
            
        public MyPicker()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

iOSRenderer:

```
  public class MyPickerRenderer:PickerRenderer
    {
        public MyPickerRenderer()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement == null) return;
            var customPicker = e.NewElement as MyPicker;

            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new UITextField
                {
                    RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always,
                    ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
                });
                SetUIbutton(customPicker.DonebuttonText);
            }
            else
            { SetUIbutton(customPicker.DonebuttonText); }
        }
        public void SetUIbutton(string doneButtonText)

        {
            UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar();
            toolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;
            toolbar.Translucent = true;
            toolbar.SizeToFit();
            UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(string.IsNullOrEmpty(doneButtonText) ? "OK" : doneButtonText,
                UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (s, ev) => { Control.ResignFirstResponder(); });
            UIBarButtonItem flexible = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
            toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { doneButton, flexible }, true);
            Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;

        }
       
    }
```

As for android, change text in **NegativeButton** like:

```
 public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        public MyPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
        private AlertDialog _dialog;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
                return;

            Control.Click += Control_Click;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker model = Element;

            var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
            if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
            {
                picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
                picker.MinValue = 0;
                picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
                picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
                picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
                picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
            }

            var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.AddView(picker);

            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
            builder.SetView(layout);
            builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
            builder.SetNegativeButton("OK ", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                _dialog = null;
            });
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Done", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
                // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }
                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
            {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            };
            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a `NumberPicker` because it displays the picker in a way I don't want

Comment: try to add the button in your renderer